# handleChallenge() is not getting called after successful execution of isCustomResponse()

Tags: authentication, ibm-mobilefirst

I am developing an application using IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation application 7.0, with AngularJS and Ionic. For the authentication I am using adapter-based authentication.

I have a single realm that protects the application, and all procedures. I've defined a Login Controller and a LoginChallangeHandler Service that handles authentication related activities:

I am basing it on the following: https://medium.com/@papasimons/worklight-authentication-done-right-with-angularjs-768aa933329c

When I login in the app, the authentication works fine by the following steps

**Step1:**
Calling `ch.submitAdapterAuthentication(options, ch.submitLoginCallback);`

**Step2:**
After successful Adapter invocation the following is called

```
ch.submitLoginCallback = function(response) {
            console.log("submitLoginCallback.response ",response);
            var isLoginFormResponse = ch.isCustomResponse(response);
            console.log("submitLoginCallback.isLoginFormResponse ",isLoginFormResponse);
            if (isLoginFormResponse){
                console.log("submitLoginCallback.calling  ");
                ch.handleChallenge(response);
            } 
        };
```

**step3:**
`ch.isCustomResponse = function(response)` is called which returns true or false.

```
ch.isCustomResponse = function(response){
            console.log("isCustomResponse.responseJSON ",response);
            //alert("response")
            if (!response || !response.responseJSON || response.responseText === null) {
                return false;

            }

            console.log("isCustomResponse.response.responseJSON ",response.responseJSON);
            console.log(typeof(response.responseJSON.authRequired) !== 'undefined');
            if (typeof(response.responseJSON.authRequired) !== 'undefined'){
                //ch.handleChallenge(response);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        };
```

**Step4:**
`ch.handleChallenge = function(response)` is called, in which we will handle the success or failure of usr authentication.

Problem is, when the authentication fails or server session logout or server session timeout, on server adapter side onAuthRequired method is called which `returnsauthRequired=true`.

```
function onAuthRequired(headers, errorMessage){
    return {
        authRequired: true,
        errorMessage: errorMessage
    };
}
```

At the client side, `ch.isCustomResponse = function(response)` is called, but the `ch.handleChallenge = function(response)` is not called after that. The execution is terminating at `ch.isCustomResponse` function and `ch.handleChallenge` is not called automatically. If I call manually like this

```
if (typeof(response.responseJSON.authRequired) !== 'undefined'){
                //ch.handleChallenge(response);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
```

at login time the `ch.handleChallenge()` is executed *twice*.

Can anyone please tell me how to solve this problem? How to call `ch.handleChallenge()` automatically when `ch.isCustomResponse()` returns either `authRequired=true` or `false`.

Answer (score 0):

when the authentication fails or server session logout or server session timeout

First you need to take the user on Login page(where user give credentials and press login) or if you login by code then you need to call this

> ch.submitAdapterAuthentication(options, ch.submitLoginCallback);

Comment: thank you, Currently I'm doing the same,but my problem statement is after successful adapter execution, ch.isCustomResponse() is called automatically with response {authRequired: true, errorMessage: null}, but the ch.handleChallenge() function is not called automatically. If incase I call the ch.handleChallenge() function manually from ch.isCustomResponse() , Then on execution of ch.submitAdapterAuthentication(options, ch.submitLoginCallback), ch.handleChallenge() function is called twice.please give you suggestion and advice to solve this issue.

Comment: Worklight must call handleChallenge method whenever isCustomResponse returns a YES value. 

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/html/refobjc-worklight-ios/html/interface_challenge_handler.html

give a try retrun "YES" from isCustomResponse.
i do not have a working code.